# Why won't my Powershot A450 power on?

Tags: troubleshooting, battery, powershot

My Canon Powershot A450 was fine but needed a battery change. Did not turn on with new batteries. Retried old, same result. Tried more new batteries, still no response. Is there a reset button? Or did it simply die?

Comment: You can try to replace the internal battery: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/220587/Canon-Powershot-A450.html?page=94